# problem in selecting a value from drop down

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having a problem in selecting a value from dropdown list. Regardless of whatever I choose only the **first value is selected always**. Please help...

Here is the code...

```
protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con;

    String strcon = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Constr"].ToString();
    try
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
        con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select user_name from user_details where role='USER'", con);     
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            da.Fill(ds);
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "user_name";
            DropDownList1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message.ToString());

    }




protected void Button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string Name = Session["name"].ToString();
    SqlConnection con;

    String strcon = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Constr"].ToString();
    try
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
        con.Open();


        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select user_name,Arival,late,Day_count from attedance where user_name='" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text + "' ", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        da.Fill(ds);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message.ToString());

    }
```

Comment: Is this running inside an UpdatePanel or something similar? Else you need to select an item on Page_Load

Comment: it is used to fetch value from table

Comment: thanks a lot.......it has to be given in page load I put it wrongly in button control.It is working now..:)

Answer (score 1):

Don't quite get your code. You've shown two button click event handlers.

The first populates the drop-down, so the first item will be selected (that's how it works).

The second one populates a gridview.

If the issue arises from clicking 'Button4' (rename buttons to make it clear what they do), then that's your issue surely?

Also, you're not closing your SqlConnection. Use a using block:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    //Do work here
}
```

EDIT: Ah, just noticed the (!IsPostBack).

Is ViewState enabled for the drop-down?

Comment: I guess (I hope) that the issue is when Button6 is clicked.  ie, Button4 is clicked, user then selects something and clicks Button6.  Agree completely about the naming and using() blocks though.

Comment: thanks a lot.......it has to be given in page load I put it wrongly in button control.It is working now..:)